# In cucumber rakefile, one failure in any one of the rake load task, subsequent rakes are not running

Tags: cucumber, rake

I have a rakefile as below and in cmd if i use "rake sanityLoadTask" and if the task2 is failing for somereason then task3 is not triggering.  !!!!!????

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:task1) do |t|

t.profile = 'default'

t.cucumber_opts = "-t @tag1"

end

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:task2) do |t|

t.profile = 'default'

t.cucumber_opts = "-t @tag2"

end

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:task3) do |t|

t.profile = 'default'

t.cucumber_opts = "-t @tag3"

end

## Load task

task :sanityLoadTask => [] do

```
Rake::Task[:task1].execute

Rake::Task[:task2].execute

Rake::Task[:task3].execute
```

end

Answer (score 1):

As soon as a Cucumber rake task fails, it makes the rake program stop.  You may wish to run the individual tasks run in separate processes, so that if they abort, the rest of the sanityLoadTask will run.

See http://www.rakefieldmanual.com/fascicles/004-ignore-failed-tasks.html for a workaround.